# wallet.dat file compromise

Tags: private-key, wallet.dat

If the private key(s) are/is in the wallet.dat file, then isn't it overly exposed to hackers?  Can't a hacker just read my C:[dir]\wallet.dat file and take all the bitcion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to protect against wallet theft?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14062/how-to-protect-against-wallet-theft)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have an unencrypted wallet.dat then this is a very real possibility. Even an encrypted wallet.dat is vulnerable without a strong password and good security practices. It's simply a list of private keys encrypted with AES. AES can't be hacked, but a weak password can. FWIW, people who've lost their password for the wallet.dat have not been able to retrieve their funds, so an encrypted wallet.dat stands the test of encryption.